# Find within large list using Contains within Linq

Tags: c#, list, foreach, console, linq-to-excel

I have two large excel files.  I am able to get the rows of these excel files into a list using linqtoexcel.  The issue is that I need to use a string from one object within the first list to **find if it is part of or contained inside another string** within an object of the second list.   I was trying the following but the process is taking to long as each list is over 70,000 items.

I have tried using an Any statement but have not be able to pull results.  If you have any ideas please share.

```
List<ExcelOne> exOne = new List<ExcelOne>();
List<ExcelTwo> exTwo = new List<ExcelTwo>();
```

I am able to build the first list and second list and can verify there are objects in the list.  Here was my thought of how I would work through the lists to find matching.  Note that once I have found the matching I want to create a new class and add it to a new list.

```
 List<NewFormRow> rows = new List<NewFormRow>();

        foreach (var item in exOne)
        {
             //I am going through each item in list one
            foreach (var thing in exTwo)
            {
                  //I now want to check if exTwo.importantRow has or 
                  //contains any part of the string from item.id
                if (thing.importantRow.Contains(item.id))
                {
                    NewFormRow adding = new NewFormRow()
                    {
                        Idfound = item.id,
                        ImportantRow = thing.importantRow
                    };
                    rows.Add(adding);
                    Console.WriteLine("added one");
                }
            }
```

If you know a quicker way around this please share.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to improve this substring approach. The question is if you have to do it here. Can't you do it where you have filled the lists? Then you don't need this additional step.

However, maybe you find this LINQ query more readable:

```
List<NewFormRow> rows = exOne
    .SelectMany(x => exTwo
        .Where(x2 => x2.importantRow.Contains(x.id))
        .Select(x2 => new NewFormRow
        {
            Idfound = x.id,
            ImportantRow = x2.importantRow
        }))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Yes this is much cleaner.  Still take about the same amount of time but there isn't much dev can do about 70k lines on an excel file.  Thanks again